# Highcharts in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

Has anyone had success using Highcharts in Node.js? I'm having the following issue using Highcharts@5.0.6 :

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts'),
    chart = Highcharts.chart(null, {
    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }],
    // ...
});
```

Which produces this error:

```
TypeError: Highcharts.chart is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts needs a browser environment to run. When you create a chart, you have to specify a DOM element/id which will hold the chart (you typed `null`). Unless you use node's library which implements DOM, using Highcharts in node environment is not possible. [The article](https://blog.davidpadbury.com/2010/10/03/using-nodejs-to-render-js-charts-on-server/) from David Padbury should shed some light on how you can use Highcharts in node.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to physically load the module.

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');

// This is how a module is loaded. Pass in Highcharts as a parameter.
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);

var chart = Highcharts.chart(null, {
    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
    }],
    // ...
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts) for reference.

Comment: I believe that just loads the Highchart exporting module. At any rate loading it produces a TypeError as well: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`